# How to use Phabricator datasource type custom field's "datasource.parameters" property?

Tags: phabricator

I find the type in the doc [Custom field](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/),but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The property `datasource.parameters` receives an array and you can use it to pass your own settings of the field. For instance, a custom field would look like this in the JSON format:

```
"custom-field": {
  "name": "Custom Field",
  "type": "datasource",
  "caption": "Choose a cool source",
  "datasource.class": "MyCustomDatasource",
  "datasource.parameters": ["my_custom_setting": "1"]
  "limit": 1,
  "required": false,
  "subtypes": ["my_form"]
}
```

And in your datasource class you can access them using `getParameter()`:

```
MyCustomDatasource.php

public function loadResults() {
    ...
    $param_value = $this->getParameter('my_custom_setting');
    \\ now you can do anything with the value
}
```